# Check Integer in list of Strings in Java

Tags: java, string, list, contains

How to check if list of string contains a specific integer in Java, what if we directly pass integer without parsing in list of string contains method in Java?

Comment: I tried 
List<String> s = {"20"}
s.contains(20) gives false
but when I gave s.contains(String.valueOf(20))) it gives true,
Is it converting 20 to ascii here?

Comment: No, it converts it to an integer, because you called `valueOf`. See the `String.valueOf` docs. A list of strings will never contain `20`, `20` isn't a string. If you want to check the content of a string to see if it's strictly an integer then you need to actually check the content of the string to see if it's strictly an integer.

Comment: @user16320675 Whoops, yep--dang it.

Comment: Details belong in the body of your Question, not Comments.

Comment: This Question needs some example data.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mix the type.
The contains method will compare like this:

s.contains(String.valueOf(20))):

```
"20".equals("20") // true
```

s.contains(20)

```
"20".equals(20) // false
```